# Computing UIVIews new width before rotation

Tags: ios, uiview, width, uiinterfaceorientation

I'd like to know the new width my `UIViewControllers` view will have after a rotation change, but I need this information already in the

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

method, so I can not access the frame or bounds property.

I tried using the layer properties `presentationLayer` and `modelLayer`, but did not found the correct solution.

Would be great if somebody know the solution or can give some food of thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem!

The method I used was called to early:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Instead I know use this:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    CGRect frame = [self.view.window convertRect:self.view.frame fromView:self.view];
    float newWidth = frame.size.width;

    // Doing my animation stuff...
}
```

This allows me to have the correct new width and animate my views properly.